# Permissions issue with symlinks over samba

Tags: permissions, samba, symbolic-link, transmission

I'm having trouble accessing some files over a samba share. Here's my setup:

- I have shared `/shared` as `Shared`
- I have a user with the same name and pwd as my Linux user in my Windows machine
- I made that user a member of the `debian-transmission` group
- There's a symlink called `/shared/Downloads/Torrents` that points to 
  `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/downloads`
- That folder is owned by `debian-transmission:debian-transmission` and its permissions are `4775` (as created by the package)

I need to be able to **read and move** files from/to /shared/Downloads/Torrents from my Windows box.

Right now, I'm able to do that locally, but I get an **access denied** error when trying to read the `Downloads` folder.

Comment: A comparable question in Ask Different: [How can you avoid error -43 when copying symlinked folder in Finder with a SAMBA share?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/68374/8546)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you enabled wide symlinks in the configuration for your share in smb.conf?

```
follow symlinks=yes
wide links = yes
```

Wide links at least is off by default as it [might be exploited](http://www.samba.org/samba/news/symlink_attack.html).

Comment: I have not, but it's the default according to http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html#samba2-CHP-8-TABLE-1. I have no problems accessing directories for which I'm the owner over symlinks (just tried)

Comment: What you need is wide links as well. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Egil: it hasn't fixed the problem, but you are on to something, as I created a link to `/home/myuser` and I can't access it either. Still, isn't "yes" the default for wide links too?

Comment: It was set to off by default following the post I linked to above (February 2010).

Comment: @Egil: ok... still, I've set `wide links = yes` both in [global] and the share, and restarted smbd, but it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: You may also need "unix extensions = no" in your [Global]

Answer (score 8):

From a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/35059/39012#comment39162_35059) on the previous answer from user [charlesbridge](https://askubuntu.com/a/35059/39012#comment39162_35059) (and from the [smb.conf docs/manpages](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)), accessing links outside of the share root requires enabling the `wide links` parameter, which requires both `follow symlinks = yes` and `unix extensions = no`. You must ensure your smb.conf has the following settings (explicitly or implicitly):

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. `unix extensions = no`

Comment: If this still doesn't work for you, [check if AppArmor is blocking your symlink target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493092/13308).

Answer (score 4):

For newer versions of Ubuntu and Samba, this will help:

```
[global]
allow insecure wide links = yes

[yourShareName]
wide links = yes
```